# filenotfounderror with SPI function

Tags: raspbian, spi

I am currently working on a personal project and im having some problems troubleshooting this particular error.

```
python3 ecg.py


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ecg.py", line 30, in <module>
    spi.open(0,0)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I was thinking it might be an issue with spidev? but i have installed spidev into the pi and still have the error so im lost right now

I have included my code below, my project is basically trying to interface with a ADC chip with my code and there are 5 channels for the ADC

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import spidev 
import time 
import os 


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# Setup Pins
gpio_pins = [22, 27, 17, 23, 24, 25] 

for gpio_pin in gpio_pins:
    GPIO.setup(gpio_pin, GPIO.OUT) # Setup pin as output
    GPIO.output(gpio_pin, GPIO.LOW) # Set output to LOW to turn off the pins

# Open SPI bus
spi = spidev.SpiDev() 
spi.open(0,0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 1350000 
time.sleep(0.0005) #for stability





# Function to read SPI data from ADAS1000 chip Channel must a integer between 0-7
def ReadChannel(channel):
    adc = spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
    print("raw data",adc)
    data = ((adc[1]&3) << 8) + adc[2]
    return data

# Define sensor channels
LA_channel = 0 
LL_channel = 1
RA_channel = 2
V1_channel = 3
V2_channel = 4


# Define delay between readings
delay = 0.5


time.sleep(0.0005) #for stability

##main loop
try:
    while True:

        # Read the  sensor data
        LAdata = ReadChannel(LA_channel)
        LLdata = ReadChannel(LL_channel)
        RAdata = ReadChannel(RA_channel)
        V1data = ReadChannel(V1_channel)
        V2data = ReadChannel(V2_channel)


        # Print our results
        print ("--------------------")
        print ("LA : {}  LL : {}  RA : {}  V1 : {}  V2 : {}".format(LAdata,LLdata,RAdata,V1data,V2data))


        # Wait before repeating loop
        time.sleep(delay)

        #os.system('clear') 

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Fixed, i did:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

then

> changed the spi to active

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.